# Unable to install Apache servicemix

Tags: installation, apache-servicemix

First time, I have successfully installed and unfortunately it was deleted. Again I have downloaded and tried to install. I am getting error in command prompt . Please see the below link for warning message.

[image: 1]

Comment: looks like a windows user permission issue ...

Comment: But  First time , I was installed successfully.

Comment: try running as administrator

Answer (score 0):

I saw this before.. its an environment variable escaping-on-Windows problem with the "space" or "parenthesis".

Try installing to c:\smx\ and it should work fine.